# Picture autocorrect

Tags: .net, image-processing

Can you recommend me a component or lib for  .net which is able to do auto-correct like Microsoft Office Picture manager does?

Or, can you tell me, how does color auto-correct work? What principles are used? 
Are used sets of effects (like saturation, brightness, contrast etc. ) or there is some "intelligent" algorithms of restoring pixels or something like that?

I know that I sound a bit messy, because I don't know much about this subject, but any information about automated color correction will be useful.

P. S. I apologize for my not so great English.

---

Thanks for your reply,

I've had problems with ImageMagick binaries, so I've decided to use AForge instead, and it has many useful functions, but I still don't know how to use them to get auto correct results.

I'm  familiar with histogram stretching for contrast auto-level, and similar things for each (rgb) color, but I'm not sure is that what software for image processing use for implementing auto-correct.

I'm trying to google this topic, but I'm stuck.

Where can I find more about techniques and algorithms for image auto-correct?

Answer (score 0):

This question belongs on stackoverflow I believe.

Anyway, ImageMagick is a command-line image tool that can to very many things on an automated basis. Download ImageMagick from http://imagemagick.org/script/download.php and try the script mentioned on this page:

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/autolevel/index.php